# NVIDIA X Server "Same As" Settings lost on every reboot

Tags: nvidia, xorg, multiple-monitors, 18.04

I'm setting my main monitor's position to "Same As" "EGA Elgato".

Example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSA03.png

The Elgato is being used to capture the Ubuntu monitor from a separate machine, where an Elgato Capture Card is being used.

This works very well, it's just that the settings keep resetting upon every reboot and I have to set them again :(

How can I get these settings to not change on reboot?

Comment: I think the problem is that in order to actually save the xorg conf, you need to change the settings as root. First save your current xorg settings as a backup `sudo mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.backup`. Then `gksudo nvidia-settings` (if you don't have gksudo you can install with `sudo apt-get install gksu`) [Reference: "Can't get Nvidia X-Server Settings to save xorg.conf" in Ubuntu Forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1357213)